# When I type certain characters, they come out as backquotes

Tags: windows-7, lenovo-laptop, typing

Very strange behavior.  Some background:

I bought a new lenovo G550 laptop, running Windows 7.  I live in Israel.

When I type certain keys, in any application, they are prefaced with the backquote (`).

These characters are: <kbd>Insert</kbd>, <kbd>Delete</kbd>, Left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (the right-hand one is fine), - (the regular dash: the one on the keypad is fine), =, 5 (the regular one), 4 (the one on the numeric keypad, whether or not Num Lock is on), and <kbd>PgDn</kbd> (the regular one).

When I press the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key with these I don't get the behavior.

Does anyone know why this is happening, or how I can fix it?

EDIT: Some friends suggested that there's some faulty wiring in the keyboard somewhere.  If I can get hold of an external keyboard, I'll be able to test it better.  In any case, I'll call technical support.

EDIT 2: When I switch the keyboard language to Hebrew, the ` comes out as a   `;`. The backquote key on Hebrew keyboards is the semicolon, so this looks like a hardware problem.  (I don't have sticky keys turned on.)

Answer (score 3):

So, after sending the computer to the fixit shop, it turns out there's a problem with the keyboard and a problem with the motherboard.  Good thing I sent it in!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible your system is using a different keyboard language than that of your keyboard is set up.

I use a Windows server as my main computer thats located in a different country, and my friends have logins so they can remote into it, and they're from the UK.

I can always tell when they log on because my @ suddenly becomes a " and vise versa.

Try setting your keyboard language.

EDIT: Set it to American English, and tell me what the shift+2 spits out, as well as the `. Might not help, but couldn't hurt.

Comment: The keyboard basically works.  It's just that some characters are prefaced with a \`.  \` comes out as \`.  Shift + 2 comes out as @.  BUT 5 comes out as \`5, or sometimes 56.  = always comes out as \`=.  I'm sending it in to be tested under warranty, and I guess they'll remove the beetles or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, but you might have "stickyKeys" enabled on your keyboard (pressing `shift` 5 times in a row)